# Google as Authorization Server

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, openid, google-openid

I'm learing some Spring security details for support OIDC and trying to implement Authorization Code Flow with GOOGLE as OpenID Provider and I have some questions:

1. Can GOOGLE OpenID Provider be used as Authorization Server in OIDC flow? If not can you provide some list of public Authorization servers (especialy that which support both OpaqueToken and JWT.
2. What is wrong with my configuration - currently I'm able to Authenticate User (Fetch Access Token and ID Token from GOOGLE and all requested profile details), unfortunately, when I'm trying use that Access token to GET data from Resource Server the response is 401.

Client - Spring Boot application with such configuration:

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .httpBasic().disable()
                .logout().disable()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.ALWAYS)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/**").authenticated()                    
                .anyRequest().denyAll()
                .and()
                .oauth2Login()
        ;
    }
```

Application properties file for client:

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          my-oidc:
            client-id: XXX.apps.googleusercontent.com
            client-secret: XXX
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
            redirect-uri: "http://localhost:8083/login/oauth2/code/redirecturi"
            scope: openid, profile
        provider:
          my-oidc:
            authorization-uri: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth
            token-uri: https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token
            jwk-set-uri: https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs
```

Resource server - Spring Boot application with such configuration:

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .formLogin().disable()
                .httpBasic().disable()
                .logout().disable()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/**").authenticated()
                .and()
                .oauth2ResourceServer(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::opaqueToken)
        ;
    }
```

Application properties file for resource server:

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        opaquetoken:
          client-id: XXX.apps.googleusercontent.com
          client-secret: XXX
          introspection-uri: "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth"
```

Authorization server - currently trying to use google OpenID Connect